# Linear Transformation of stock price

Tags: time-series

Suppose, using market data for a stock, at a tick level, I arrive at a time series, I(t), which is a linear transform of the stock price time series, S(t). I(t) is not leading S(t) and the lagged correlation between I(t) and S(t) is close to one for a small t.

My question is that for such a case, does the researcher achieve anything at all? Any analysis which can be performed on I(t) can be performed on S(t) and since I(t) doesnt lead, we dont have any advantage at all.

Not sure if what I have said makes sense but would like to know experts' opinion on the same.

Regards

Comment: Could you please provide some more background info because your question is not clear as it stands - esp. concerning what you want to achieve with this lin. transformation

Comment: I was trying to build a predictive model but my result ended up replicating the underlying very closely with a small lag. My question is do I gain anything if I dont have a leading indicator, the predictor, even if I am able to design an indicator of underlying price using market data.

Comment: I don't see how this could be useful.